# using wx.Grid is there a way to add multiple rows in the column header

Tags: python, header, grid, wxwidgets

[two rows on a grid header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiCpw.png)

This one is was created using tkinter lib  but I want o achieve the same thing using wx.Grid in python

Comment: What have you currently tried? Can you show us an example of your code?

Comment: @HectorMontes, there is a long standing ticket on trac.wxwidgets.org about that. So I don't thin it is possible right now. There was a plan to implement it with this year GSoC, but wx didn't get to the program. So unless you have an implementation and can submit a patch to the wx C++ mainline, it will probably be tried next year GSoC. Nobody currently needs this feature (Vadim included), so it stays open. Patches welcome!

Comment: thanks @Igor for the answer,  I will take a look to see if I can develop something, I was just  wondering if there was something already in place that  I was missing before starting.

Comment: @HectorMontes, ok. just remember - it is preferred to be in a C++ rather than python. Python will acquire this functionality on the next release cycle. Good luck.